# Draggable item malfunction in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div called `BlueWindow` and I want it to be draggable and I tried to make it as they say in the w3schools but when I run the html page the element can't be dragged and i don't know why this is happening. It is supposed to be draggable all around the page by pressing the header and dragging. I don't know why the js code isn't working here. https://codepen.io/Fropis/pen/rgVOpy
Apparently the snippet works but in my program it doesn't so check in the codepen the whole code of it

```js
function fecharBlueto(){
  document.getElementById("BlueWindow").style.display="none";
}

// Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("BlueWindow"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV: 
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#BlueWindow{
  position: absolute;
  width:1900px;
  height:1500px;
  left:1500px;
  top:550px;
  border-radius:10px black solid;
}

#BlueWindowheader{
  height: 100px;
    background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#closeBlue{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: none;
    padding:5px;  
    top: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
}

#JoanaPTexto{
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px grey;
  font-size:50px;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#DocImgBlue{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: none;
  padding:40px; 
}

#bottomBlue{
  background-color:white;
  height:1415px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5%;
}

#MariaDoc{
  position: absolute;
  left:140px;
  top:575px;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PF1.1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="BlueWindow">
        <div id="BlueWindowheader">
                <header class="windowTop1">
                <img id="closeBlue" onclick="fecharBlueto()" class="X" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Actions-dialog-close-icon.png">
                <h1 id="JoanaPTexto">Joana's Phone</h1>
                </header>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomBlue">
            <div id="doc1">
                <div id="doc1header">
                    <img id="DocImgBlue" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/file.png">
                </div>
                    <h1 id="MariaDoc">Doc-exemplo-Maria</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
<script src="PF1.1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: the snippet seems to work to me - I can drag and drop the blue window?

Comment: Yeah it works here but not in my program i don't know why will post the codepen with the whole program

Comment: @FernandoAlbuquerque then it means the problem is not in this part of the code

Comment: Worked for me as well - check your console for errors. Maybe you have some other script throwing an error breaking your other scripts

Comment: So how do i solve it? In the codepen I gave you the window isn't draggable

Comment: Already did and still not draggable

Comment: Open the codepen and the browser console. I'm getting error**s**. The first is about `nav1` being `null`.

Comment: Already deleted it but it still doesn't work @ChrisG

Comment: Updated the codepen to be correct and with no errors

Comment: Any ideas of what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, give `z-index: 10000;` for the `#BlueWindow` so there's no other elements (layers) which is top on this element and physically catches the mouse click/drag event.
You need to fix your layers in your app.
You can also disable the unused element's `pointer-events: none;`. In that case when you enable only on those elements the pointer events which you use, there will be less overlap/intersection.
You can simply test which element overlaps, just use the right click and inspect element. It will select that element which is catching the events (always that one which is on the top from the layers).
In my case the `#janela` and the `.navbar` hides it, depending on the resolution. And these elements are selected when I try to inspecting the `#BlueWindow` element.

Comment: Oh okay. So the pointer-events:none; is usable for all of the elements in the html. if i want to make the window that pops up when u click the folder icon to be draggable and the calendar as well and the window `#BlueWindow`? @golddragon007

Comment: You can use `pointer-events:none;` on those items which doesn't need to catch any mouse events or you need to play with the `z-index`.

Comment: ok ty man. Can you tell me if it is possible to make the calendar window draggable as well because i tried to play with the z-index in there and didn't work if u can tell me how to make it draggable plz

Comment: If i use the `pointer-events:none;` in the css it isn't possible to drag the items and the js to close the windows also stops working